# Cannot find edge cases for python code for Project Euler #1 in Hackerrank

Tags: python, algorithm

For problem #1 for Project Euler in hackerrank.com, this is the problem:

If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

**Input Format**
First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.

**Output Format**
For each test case, print an integer that denotes the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N.

**Constraints:**
1 ≤ T ≤ 105
1 ≤ N ≤ 109

```
def multSums(num, div):
    hiMult = int( (num-1)/ div )
    return int(div * hiMult * ( hiMult + 1 ) / 2)

while True:
    try:
        n = int(input())
    except EOFError:
        break

    result = multSums(n, 3) + multSums(n, 5) - multSums(n, 15)
    if result > 0:
        print(result)
```

For this problem, if I used a list comprehension to get all the multiples, I would fail the test cases because it would take too long. Instead, I decremented the number (all multiples below N), divided the number by `div` (3, 5, 15) and used a summation formula that sums consecutive numbers `hiMult * ( hiMult + 1 ) / 2` and use the result to multiply by `div`. I need to do this with `15` to remove duplicate multiples: which results to `multSums(n, 3) + multSums(n, 5) - multSums(n, 15)`.

However, when I submit this, the code works ONLY for the sample test case and any custom test cases that I could think of. What edge cases could I be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input starts with a line `T` that indicates the number of lines to follow. There's nothing in the code you posted accounting for that line. While you don't need to use it (since you just break once there's no more input) you do need to skip it; otherwise you'll output one erroneous result and shift the remaining results down one.

Try adding an `input()` call before your `while` loop, to skip the first line of input.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any edge cases you need to handle, but you do have to generalize the two input numbers (ie. `3` and `5`).

```
multSums(n, i) + multSums(n, j) - multSums(n, i * j)
```

Also, you can avoid using the `int()` conversion everywhere if you specify integer division (the default in python2) using 2 slashes.

```
>>> 5 // 2
2
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and is off topic.

Comment: @BiRico Isn't the question whether there are edge cases and whether the custom function can be generalized to work for all input values?

Comment: The inputs aren't generalized for this question. It has to be 3 and 5.

Comment: @frankhernan in what python you are? if you are in python3 you better do as @BrendanAbel say and use integer division `//` because `/` give a float and to N sufficiently big you lost precision when you convert it to int, for example `(3**35)//3 != int((3**35)/3)`